# Why was the implement of __pool_alloc_base in gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/pool_allocator.cc?

Tags: gcc, stl, implementation

when I read pool_allocator in STL, I found that many functions of the __pool_alloc_base class are implemented in gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/pool_allocator.cc, why is that designed? Why not put the implementation of these functions in the pool_allocator.h?

pool_allocator.h

```
class __pool_alloc_base {
protected:
    ...
    _GLIBCXX_CONST _Obj *volatile *_M_get_free_list(size_t __bytes) throw();

    __mutex & _M_get_mutex() throw();

    // Returns an object of size __n, and optionally adds to size __n
    // free list.
    void *_M_refill(size_t __n);

    // Allocates a chunk for nobjs of size size.  nobjs may be reduced
    // if it is inconvenient to allocate the requested number.
    char *_M_allocate_chunk(size_t __n, int &__nobjs);
};
```